# How to locate JDK to use BlueJ in my system

Tags: java, eclipse, bluej

I am using Windows XP 32 bit system. I have java directory in my C:
Also when I searched, I found that Java is installed in C:\Windows\system32\ directory.
When I run `java -version` command in my command prompt, I got below result:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I am able to run Java program in eclipse in my system. 
I installed BlueJ in my system. When I open it, I got a pop up informing me that "BlueJ could not find a Java Development Kit. A JDK must be installed to run BlueJ. Click browse to locate JDK." I am not able to locate JDK in my system.

Can someone help me to locate JDK in my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have most probably installed Java Runtime Environment (JRE) and not Java Development Kit (JDK)

A simple explanation is that you need JRE to run Java Programs and JDK to create them. BlueJ is an IDE for developing Java programs, so it will need JDK.

You can download it from here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Make sure you choose the correct version for you OS (Windows, x86)

Comment: Can you explain your statement - `JRE to run Java Programs and JDK to create them`?

Comment: Sure! Java source code needs to be compiled before it can be run. Compiler is part of JDK. Then, after compilation you can run the compiled code using any Java Runtime Environment. Btw you don't have to install both - Java Development Kit includes a JRE.

Comment: My issue is specific for BlueJ. When I open it, it search for `Java VM Executable files`. When I give the path `c:\windows\system32\java.exe` - it prompt error - `Choosen file does not appear in Java SDK`

Comment: You write in your question this:

"BlueJ could not find a Java Development Kit. A JDK must be installed to run BlueJ. Click browse to locate JDK." I am not able to locate JDK in my system.

so its JDK it could not find, or what you say in your latest comment is another error?

Have you tried to install Java Development Kit from the link I sent to you and point the BlueJ to the JDK location?